# Is there a way to compile a single class file and dependencies with maven

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, serverless

I recently started with a company that uses java for their AWS lambda functions. Their deployment strategy is such that the project will contain code for multiple lambda functions, and once compiled, each individual lambda function contains the entire project .jar file. Is there a way to compile the project code such that only a single class (in lambda terms, the handler), and its' dependencies/imports are compiled into a smaller .jar, rather than compiling the entire project?

Comment: If you need to compile a single class which needs dependencies you have to create a separate project incl. deps and put only the single class into that project...

Comment: Are there any common tools or libraries that would help me with that? My previous company had an almost identical issue, building a repo for serverless and having the entire repo in every lambda. Surely I'm not the only person to experience this problem? I just want to compile from file out, rather than from project down.

Comment: The file (Serverless) parts needs dependencies to be compiled which you define in your pom file ... (classpath)... finally you build a jar which contains very little (as far as I know)... A project is usually nothing else than compiling a number of files... but no one will prevent to have only a single file in your project..can you make an example project on github or alike?

Comment: I *think* you're asking how to get only the *actual* dependencies for a given function. ProGuard and similar tools can do that, with the caveat that anything relying solely on static analysis can miss dynamic dependencies. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/30655675/438992 but searching the web will provide other solutions.

Comment: ProGuard sounds very promising. I'll try it!